# Three.js SubdivisionModifier null error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using the Three.js library and attempting to apply a Subdivision Modifier to a model.  I am able to load a model successfully, and I am able to apply a subdivision modifier to a CubeGeometry (for example) successfully as well.  The code below works when the line commented below is removed, but then of course there will be no "subdivisioning".  When the code is run as is, the JavaScript console gives the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'u' of null".  My best guess is that the clone() method was not yet complete and so the modify() method threw a null exception.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "models/parrot.js", function( geometry ) 
{
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set(-50,25,0);
    scene.add( mesh );

    var smooth = THREE.GeometryUtils.clone( geometry );
    smooth.mergeVertices();
    var divisions = 2;
    var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier( divisions );
    modifier.modify( smooth );   // This is the line causing the error
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( smooth, material );
    mesh2.position.set(50,25,0);
    scene.add( mesh2 ); 
});
```

Comment: Can you upload a working live example of this somewhere?

Comment: Sure can, here it is:
http://www.adelphi.edu/~stemkoski/Three.js/Subsurf.html

Comment: Uhm, that seems to be a bug. Reported it here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2132

Answer (score 2):

you could try doing `modifier.supportUVs = false` to suppress UV errors.